# Why beautiful soup select by class return empty list by find_all works?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse out the top 100 hot hits for a certain day from billboards with beautiful soup. I tried to select the section by class name, but it does not work. I tried to use find_all by class, and it works.
Why does find_all only work in this case?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

billboard_website = "https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/2019-05-09"
response = requests.get(f"{billboard_website}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")


print(soup.select(".chart-element__information__song text--truncate color--primary")) # returns an empty list

print(soup.find_all(class_="chart-element__information__song text--truncate color--primary")) # returns the full list
```

Comment: In the context of a CSS selector, I believe spaces indicate nested elements, and you have a space between `truncate` and `color`.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried a different class, ```print( soup.select(‘.chart-list__wrapper’) )``` still returns an empty list.

Comment: As fetched by `requests.get()`, that page does not contain any occurrences of `chart-list__wrapper`.  (requests does not do javascript.)

Comment: `[i.text for i in soup.select('.chart-element__information__song')]`  multi-valued class you need to join separate classes with a `.` in css class selectors. Or, simply choose one of the classes if appropriate. In this case, you can just use the first class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both work depending on what you are trying to achieve, as explained in the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)

Essentially `find_all(class_="Class1 Class2")` is almost equivalent to `select(.Class1.Class2)` the only difference is that the former requires the exact string while the latter requires CSS selectors but does not care about the order[1], e.g.

Say you have the following element `<p class="A B">`

find_all(class_="B A") **won't match** but `select(.B.A)` will

If you fix your syntax to `soup.select(".chart-element__information__song.text--truncate.color--primary")` it should return the same values

[1] - There are other differences such as support for regex, which are explained in the docs